# Border gradient disappears on larger resolution screen

Tags: html, css, border, linear-gradients

When I zoom out my screen the borders disappear on some sides. I'm assuming it's because the padding of `0.05rem` is too small to detect on higher-res screens. Is there a good way to go about fixing this?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mlelien/pen/drdBGy?editors=1100#0)

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.module-border-wrap {
  max-width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, purple);
  padding: 0.05rem;
}

.module {
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="module-border-wrap">
  <div class="module">
    Lorem ipsum dolor
  </div>
</div>
```

100% zoomed:

[image]

90% zoomed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would optimize the code using one element and multiple background. Not sure if it will fix the issue on your side but it seems fine on my side:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.module {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#222, #222) padding-box, 
    linear-gradient(to right, red, purple) border-box;
  color: white;
  border: 0.05rem solid transparent;
  padding: 2rem;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="module">
  Lorem ipsum dolor
</div>
```

Comment: That does not produce the same gradient.